# How can I make this CoffeeScript object work?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm learning to use a small library called `Bootbox` in my Twitter `Bootstrap`-enabled `Rails` v4.2 application.

There are several examples on the main page in order to test some of the functionality. In these examples they reference a small JS file that contains an object called `Example`.

I converted this to CoffeeScript as the following:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

jQuery ->

  ###*
  # This tiny script just helps us demonstrate
  # what the various example callbacks are doing
  ###

  Example = ->
    'use strict'
    elem = undefined
    hideHandler = undefined
    that = {}

    that.init = (options) ->
      elem = $(options.selector)
      return

    that.show = (text) ->
      clearTimeout hideHandler
      elem.find('span').html text
      elem.delay(200).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut()
      return

    that

  $("#search-link").click ->
    bootbox.dialog
      message: 'I am a custom dialog'
      title: 'Custom title'
      buttons:
        success:
          label: 'Success!'
          className: 'btn-success'
          callback: ->
            Example.show 'great success'
            return
```

There is no issue with the actual Bootbox functionality. However, I can see an error in the console when I click the button that within the dialog box:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Example.show is not a function
```

It seems pretty clear, I thought, that I have set up an object `Example` with a class method called "show". I am definitely no JS/CoffeeScript expert though, which is the reason for my question.

Comment: You need to initialize `Example` some how. `Example().show 'great success'` should do it. I dont know if you need it to be variable or an instance you can call multiple times. but you can save yourself that by doing: `Example = (-> ... )()` and then you dont have to touch anything else

Comment: Judging by the `init()`, you're going to need to do something like this: `Example = (-> ... )()`  and then `Example.init({selector: JQUERY_SELECTOR})` right after the `()` in the line below.

Comment: right. because `JQUERY_SELECTOR` needs to be YOUR selector, as in, you need to replace that with something like `"#mydiv"` or `".container"`

Comment: Javier please put that in an answer so I can award it to you. Working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Example = (->
    'use strict'
    elem = undefined
    hideHandler = undefined
    that = {}

    that.init = (options) ->
      elem = $(options.selector)
      return

    that.show = (text) ->
      clearTimeout hideHandler
      elem.find('span').html text
      elem.delay(200).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut()
      return

    that
 )()
 Example.init({selector: JQUERY_SELECTOR})
```